# Making the thumbnails in the backend Media section bigger

Tags: admin, media-library

So I uploaded a lot of similar looking photos, and uploaded a duplicate or two.

I go into the backend to the Media panel, but alas, each row has a small thumbnail, making it time consuming to figure out which ones are the duplicates, or just to tell them apart.

How would I make the image bigger? At the moment it is 60x60 but 128x128 would be nicer or maybe even larger!

Just to clarify, I am talking about the admin area, not the frontend/theme

Comment: hmmm I suspect I will need to remove the 'icon' column and replace it with a column of my own

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any way of hooking into this. Following the lead of `wp_get_attachment_image` takes nowhere...

```
// wp-admin/includes/class-wp-media-list-table.php
// line 200

case 'icon':
    $attributes = 'class="column-icon media-icon"' . $style;
?>
    <td <?php echo $attributes ?>><?php
        if ( $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image( $post->ID, array( 80, 60 ), true ) ) {
            if ( $this->is_trash || ! $user_can_edit ) {
                echo $thumb;
            } else {
?>
            <a href="<?php echo get_edit_post_link( $post->ID, true ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'Edit &#8220;%s&#8221;' ), $att_title ) ); ?>">
                <?php echo $thumb; ?>
            </a>

<?php           }
        }
```

---

[image]

Inspecting the output we see that the image is being forcefully resized, so manipulating the DOM can be an alternative.

```
add_action( 'admin_head-upload.php', 'wpse_59182_bigger_media_thumbs' );

function wpse_59182_bigger_media_thumbs() 
{
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
            $('.wp-list-table img').each(function(){
                $(this).removeAttr('width').css('max-width','100%');
                $(this).removeAttr('height').css('max-height','100%');
            });
            $('.column-icon').css('width', '130px');
        });     
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

**edit by Question asker ( Tom ):**

I applied the solution in this question, and these are the results:

[image: result of jquery in upload screen]

Comment: It isn't my planned solution, or as flexible, but it answers the question upt o 130px!

Comment: I still gotta learn how to suggest patches to the core, this one would be much welcome, IMO that is... Just out of curiosity, what do you prefer: replacing the column or hack the DOM? And what would you consider *flexible?*

Comment: As I speculated, removing the icon column and putting a new column in its place would let us pick any image size

Comment: 130px is fine for me though so don't feel pressed

Comment: Nope, not feeling pressed, it was speculation as well. . . . . But surely those 60x60 are almost useless, will incorporate this in my daily hacks :o)

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on brasofilo's solution I used the below to enlarge the thumbnails within the media uploader / gallery

Its far from perfect and needs more time spent - most noticeably with the active draggable area remaining the same as previous when resorting - but if you're dealing with 10's of similar images attached to a single post I found it a huge help as is.

```
add_action( 'admin_head-media-upload-popup', 'make_media_thumbs_bigger' );

function make_media_thumbs_bigger() 
{
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready( function($) {

            $('#media-upload img').each(function(){
                $(this).removeAttr('width').css('max-width','100%');
                $(this).removeAttr('height').css('max-height','100%');
            });

            $('#media-upload .media-item').each(function(){
                $(this).removeAttr('style');
            });

            $('#media-upload .media-item ').css('height', '96px');

            $('#media-upload a.describe-toggle-on, #media-upload a.describe-toggle-off').click(function() {
                     $(this).parent().removeAttr('style');
                     $(this).next('TABLE.slidetoggle').find('IMG').removeAttr('style'); 
            });

            $('#media-upload a.describe-toggle-off').click(function() {
                     $(this).parent().css('height', '96px');
            });


        });     
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: Considering 3.5 is out within days and revamps the entire media uploader, does this work in 3.5RC3?

Comment: no idea sorry - this was just a quick and dirty fix using 3.4.2. Its 90% functional, the remaining 10% to make it perfect could take some time..

Comment: The hook still works for plugins' upload popup windows, which don't have the new interface. :::: I tried your code, but unfortunately, it messes with the thickbox display, at least in 3.5. :::: I reduced it to [the bare minimum](http://pastebin.com/VyKX4gAs). If it helps, update your Answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

What your asking isn't a "simple" fix. If you're serious about getting larger thumbs I'd start by looking at the `wp-admin/class-wp-media-list-table.php` file, or here in the [PHPXref site](http://lab.yukei.net/wp-trunk/nav.html?wp-includes/widgets.php.html) (Around line 203). You can examine the code to see how it's generated and decide how to adjust it from there

Comment: I know, I kind of did that already and came to the conclusion in my comment. Though i haven't actually attempted that yet so if it works I'll post my own answer